# Get all the pages inherited from the certain page in Episerver

Tags: c#, episerver

There is an abstract base page

```
public abstract class BasePage : PageData
```

There are some pages that are inherited from this page

```
public class ChildPage : BasePage
public class ChildPage2 : BasePage
```

I need to retrieve all the pages that are inherited from the BasePage.
In **PropertyCriteria** I could use only ChildPage and ChildPage2 for the search by **PageTypeID**. So this approach would not solve the issue in my case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your most viable options are to 1) retrieve all pages (with **GetChildren** or **GetDescendants**, depending on content structure) of the base type, or 2) use **Find**.

Episerver Find makes this kind of thing trivial, provided your site actually uses Find. :/

A third (not recommended) option would be to identify all of the sub-types and use multiple **FindPagesWithCriteria** calls, but that would be *slow*. FPWC is entirely uncached, and results in DB calls.

Personally, I never use FindPagesWithCriteria for anything other than certain administrative features not dealing with rendering the actual site.

Comment: Thanks Ted, I will try